# FFT Using Pic Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, dsp, frequency-measurement, fft, harmonics

Good Evening,

I am fairly unfamiliar with DSP and want to engage in a project. I wish to perform a FFT on the source current going into a non-linear load and observe its harmonic content on an LCD. I understand the basic circuit setup but I am having a hard time understanding how it interacts with the microcontroller.  Fundamental frequency is 60Hz, voltage is 120, max current is 20A. I know I will need a CT or differential amplifier since the microcontroller cannot sustain those high values.

Do any of you have any resources that can help me out?

Comment: Do I understand right, that you wish to FFT the current? For that you can use a current sensor IC, e.g. the ACS722.

Answer (score 1):

Microchip has a whole line of PIC microcontrollers with DSP capabilities, aptly named dsPIC.  They are essentially PIC24 micros with DSP features added, including:

```
hardware multiply–accumulate (MAC)
barrel shifting
bit reversal
hardware support for loop indexing
```

There are several code examples using dsPICs for doing FFT, such as [this one](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/CE018_FFT_DSPlib_101007.zip).

Here is [an article](http://www.nutsvolts.com/blog/post/turn_your_16_bit_micro_experimenter_into_a_powerful_digital_signal_processo) describing how to use a dsPIC33 to display FFT on an LCD display.

You can find many more resources by Googling for:

```
dspic fft microchip library
```

Comment: While you are conceptually right, a PIC 24 is actually a dsPIC with the DSP part removed.  The original 24 bit core parts were all DSPs, dsPIC30F to be exact.  Yes, a pedantic historical point, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a voltage divider and shunt, or the safer voltage and current transformers to reduce the voltage and current to about 1 V ac.

You will need to filter the signal to prevent aliasing and sample the 1 V voltages with an ADC.

This is where the fun starts and I suspect it will be easier to multiply the sampled waveforms on the PIC with tables of sin(60 Hz) sin(300 Hz) and sin(420 Hz) as the even and third harmonics are not common in power systems.

Try doing a FFT in Python first.

Answer (score -1):

> FFT Using Pic Microcontroller

there are plenty of FFT code, both floating point or fixed point versions, for you to explore. just get a copy and compile it on your target.

> I am having a hard time understanding how it interacts with the microcontroller.

that's a totally different question than your title would suggest. typically you measure the current by performing an adc on it.